# How to make a python variable persist between chunks in a markdown notebook?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

Variable are not retained from one chunk to the next in notebook mode, but they are retained when knitting the markdown document to html.

I made a sample document available as a [gist called pythonvariables.Rmd](https://gist.github.com/paulrougieux/fc61e3bf7ab4b6749e608d18301b4943), the content of this file is:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
```

```{python}
x = 1 
```

```{python}
print(x)
```

```{r}
print(py$x)
```
````

In Rstudio version 1.1.453, in notebook mode, when running one chunk after the other, the output of the `print(x)` python chunk is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rougipa\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpQFW3Rj\chunk-code-1d44920f50.txt", line 1, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

However the issue doesn't appear when the Rmd is compiled to html. The output of the `print(x)` python chunk is **1** as expected.

Comment: It's related to the third comment by pjcrosbie in this knitr bug request: [Python environment persistance across chunks #1440](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1440).

Comment: Gists can disappear or change over time, could you include the (current) source of the Rmarkdown document to keep this question self-sufficient?

Comment: If a question is related to RStudio, please state its version. Without that information, a blind guess is that the latest (preview) version might have fixed your problem: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality works in Rstudio preview 1.2.747. Question kept for historical purposes.